# PostgreSQL - WHERE id IN(array) returns error: invalid input syntax for type integer:

Tags: javascript, arrays, postgresql, pg

I am using a `pg` in with `nodejs`. I have a simple query:

```
const processedAlerts = [
180, 186, 192, 198,
204, 210, 216, 222,
228, 234, 240, 246,
258]
response = await pool.query(`UPDATE alert_notification SET emailed = true WHERE id IN($1)`,[processedAlerts]);
```

I am getting following error:
`error: invalid input syntax for type integer: "{"180","186","192","198","204","210","216","222","228","234","240","246","258"}"`

When I copy-paste the same numbers from the array into the IN() part of the query like so:

```
response = await pool.query(`UPDATE alert_notification SET emailed = true WHERE id IN(180, 186, 192, 198,
204, 210, 216, 222,
228, 234, 240, 246,
258)`);
```

All will run with no issues.

I have checked and made sure by mapping over the array that the items are recognized as numbers (based on the error - complaining about them not being an integer).

I have tried a number of ways, converting it to the string, to get rid of the " around the numbers. Of course, that would not work again as it would be a string.

I have also tried to map over the numbers and parseInt() each of them. Hopeless I know as the numbers are already numbers, which would only give me the same result. BUT I don't see what other options I have converting this to the list of numbers?

I have searched around for other ways on how to update multiple rows based on the IDs from the array but I keep finding articles about how to update arrays in the DB rather than rows based on the list of numbers in the array.

I am really thankful for any reply from anyone that managed to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `""` instead

```
response = await pool.query("UPDATE alert_notification SET emailed = true WHERE id IN($1)",[processedAlerts]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried it just now. It will give me the same error.